# WiX installer problem with evaluating <Condition> when trying to copy a file

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm running Wix (3.5) and trying to conditionally copy a file if a particular feature is to be installed by the user.  I have two features, with IDs 'BaseFeature' and 'ExtrasFeature'.  I've seen discussions that I can create a <Condition> like the following:

`<Condition>

  <![CDATA[&ExtrasFeature=3]]>

</Condition>`


that will make my file copying only occur if the Extras feature is chosen. However, it doesn't work--the value of &ExtrasFeature is not 3 when I choose to install it (the file isn't copied.)  When I change the condition to NOT (&ExtrasFeature=3) and choose to install the feature, the file is copied.  The question: what should the syntax actually be to get this to correctly evaluate? What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't work. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/09/feature-states-in-component-conditions/.